# how to fetch unknown column in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there an operator in Oracle that fetch a column of a row in a result set without having to specify the column's name. I want something like:

```
for row in (select * from table1)
loop
  for col in row
  loop
     // do stuff with col
  end loop;
end loop;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In static SQL, no.

If you were using dynamic SQL (via DBMS_SQL), you could describe the statement and iterate over the columns.  But if the query itself is not dynamic, it would almost certainly increase the complexity of the code and decrease the maintainability if you were to move toward using DBMS_SQL rather than simply coding the column names that you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in function for this. You will have to use DBMS_SQL package in order to use dynamic SQL : http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/oracle/bipack/ch02_02.htm